# How to find dead code in a jenkins build in java?

Tags: java, jenkins, build

I am searching for an analyser, who is able to find dead code in java in a (jenkins) build.

Is there any known plugin / build tool to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sonarqube?
Here is how to detect dead code with it.

http://www.sonarqube.org/detect-dead-code-and-calls-to-deprecated-methods-with-sonar-squid/

And here is a guide how to configure jenkins to use sonarqube.

https://lasithapetthawadu.wordpress.com/2014/05/03/configure-jenkins-with-sonarqube-for-static-code-analysis-and-integration/

Comment: only finds unused protected and private methods.  looking for something that - given some entry points - can find all unused classes, methods, constants, etc.